# speed up request handling in django rest framework for geodjango

Tags: django-rest-framework, geodjango

I have an application that is using geodjango for handling geographic data. Frontend react app sends requests to django rest api with defined query parameters which include boundary of map for data to download and other parameters to use for filtering. Considerable amount of time is spent for waiting (TTFB) and can sometime take ~15-20s which is unacceptable. Is there any way to speed up the query handling in django:
Here is the serializer:

```
class DecisionsGeomSerializerPoints(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model= DecisionsGeom
    fields = ['id']
    geo_field = 'point'
```

Model has much more variables but the serializer is using just two

Here is the viewset:

```
class DecisionsGeomViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = DecisionsGeom.objects.all()
serializer_class = DecisionsGeomSerializerPoints

def createPoly(self,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax):
    poly = Polygon(((ymin,xmin ), (ymin, xmax), (ymax, xmax), (ymax, xmin), (ymin, xmin)))
    return poly

def get_queryset(self):
    bbox = self.request.query_params.get('bbox',None)
    start_date = self.request.query_params.get('start_date',None)
    end_date = self.request.query_params.get('end_date', None)
    category = self.request.query_params.get('category',None)
    investor = self.request.query_params.get('investor',None)
    if start_date == "undefined" or start_date=="" or start_date==None:
        start_date="2000-01-01"
    if end_date == "undefined" or end_date==""or end_date==None:
        end_date=datetime.now().date()
    queryset = PozwoleniaGeom.objects.all()
    bounds=bbox.split(',')
    polygon = self.createPoly(float(bounds[0]),float(bounds[1]),float(bounds[2]),float(bounds[3]))
    if bbox is not None :
        queryset = DecisionsGeom.objects.filter(point__bboverlaps=polygon).filter(decision_date__gte=start_date).filter(decision_date__lt=end_date)
    if category != None and category !="undefined" and category !="":
        queryset=queryset.filter(category=category)
    if investor != None and investor !="undefined" and investor !="":
        queryset=queryset.filter(Q(investor_surname__icontains=investor)|Q(investor_name__icontains=investor)|Q(investor_name__icontains=investor))
    return queryset
```

Is there any possibility to optimize this to shorten the time?

Comment: Is it django that is slow here, or your `createPoly` method?  How large and optimized are your tables?  How are the joins performing?  I would first do some basic instrumentation, even just with `time.perf_counter() ... print(time.perf_counter() - start` to see what exactly is slow.

Comment: Thanks. I have measured time spent on these methods but those values are negligable.I concluded it must be serializer's fault, because the time runs after methods are executed. I have found this info here saying that modelserializers take a lot of time to serialize lots of data:https://hakibenita.com/django-rest-framework-slow. However I need GeoFeatureModelSerializer which parses data to consumable geojson. What could I do with this?

Comment: Its hard to say.  I have never seen any relevant speed issues with serializers of any kind, though they are slower than doing it by hand, and slower if they are model based.  Still, that shouldn't affect anything to the level you are dealing with.  I'd suggest recreating this in a test file (just use manage.py as an example) and try to narrow down what is taking the time.  Take your query and see how long it takes to execute that to a list, try creating the resultset by hand, etc.  Helps if you have a representative sample locally.  For me, its 99.5% of the time a slow query